# Why do I get 'int' is not subscriptable

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, dictionary, for-loop

where I want it to print out:

'HTTP ERROR

Successful Error

401: unauthorized'

so basically, I have created a function called def create_error_dictionary(error_codes,error_description), and what it does is that it would take the numbers of error_codes, and the string from error_descriptions and make the number the key of the dictionary, and the string the value of the dictionary. Then it returns the dictionary to the main, where it is used in def get_error_code_information (error,error_code_dictionary, error_category_dictionary). This function prints out the

HTTP ERROR

Successful Error

401: unauthorized

2 the .split() part, is to split 'status:HTTP/2.401', so that the list would look like this: [' 2 ', ' 401 '] after that, I made a for loop, to change the type from str to int, so that I can use it in my print statement, for indexing. But the problem is that when I run, there is a TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable. I'm stuck on how to print this information out, and also I would like to know if there is a way, that allows me to go from create_error_dictionary, to get_error_code_information without going to the main.

```
def create_error_dictionary(error_codes, error_descriptions):
    error_code_dict = {}
    v = 0
    for i in error_codes:
        error_code_dict[i] = error_descriptions[v]
        v += 1

    return error_code_dict
    


def get_error_code_information(error, error_code_dictionary, error_category_dictionary):

    split_num_HTTP_error = error.split('/')
    split_num_error = split_num_HTTP_error[1].split('.')
    for char in split_num_error:
        split_int_error = int(char)
    print(f'HTTP ERROR\n {error_category_dictionary[split_int_error[0]]} Error\n {split_int_error[1]}:{error_code_dictionary[split_int_error[1]]}')
          
          
          

          
error_codes = [400, 401, 402]

error_descriptions = ['Bad Request', 'Unauthorized', 'Payment Required']

error_category_dictionary={1:'Information', 2:'Successful', 3:'Redirection'}


a = create_error_dictionary(error_codes, error_descriptions)

print(get_error_code_information('status:HTTP/2.402',a, error_category_dictionary))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a loop:

```
for char in split_num_error:
    split_int_error = int(char)
```

which is followed by code which does:

```
print(f'HTTP ERROR\n {error_category_dictionary[split_int_error[0]]} Error\n {split_int_error[1]}:{error_code_dictionary[split_int_error[1]]}')
```

Note how it indexes `split_int_error` at index 0 and 1, despite `split_int_error` being a single (not subscriptable) `int`.

Did you perhaps mean to do something like:

```
split_int_error = [int(char) for char in split_num_error]
```

so it was a `list` of all the integer converted components of `split_num_error`?

Comment: yes i meant it to be a list. so instead now what i've done is i've replaced split_int_error = int(char) with list_.append(int(char)) so it would go into the list_.I'm a beginner at coding so i'm not sure what you did there in the top. But now, It does print without a error, but at the end, it would also print a 'none'. Do you know why?

Comment: @HughJohnson: The `None` is because you printed the result of calling `get_error_code_information`, but `get_error_code_information` has no explicit return value, so it implicitly returns `None`. The code I used was a list comprehension (listcomp for short) that is basically an easy way to build a `list` from an input iterable one element at a time (similar to a loop that explicitly `append`s to an existing `list`, but more efficient and less verbose).

Comment: so how would i code it so that it doesn't return a none?

Comment: @HughJohnson: You use a `return` statement? Assuming it has some meaningful return? Otherwise, you just don't `print` the result of the call and the `None` gets ignored.